Binary Bomb Phase_5 (Input two integers)
I need help with figuring out my two integers to defuse phase_5. Running gdb returns "%d %d" which is how I know it's scanning for two ints. I try to follow the compare and jump statements but get lost soon after,
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x00000000004015b9 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00000000004015bd <+4>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
   0x00000000004015c2 <+9>:     lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00000000004015c7 <+14>:    mov    $0x402573,%esi
   0x00000000004015cc <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004015d1 <+24>:    call   0x401150 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x00000000004015d6 <+29>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000000004015d9 <+32>:    jle    0x401625 <phase_5+108>
   0x00000000004015db <+34>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
   0x00000000004015df <+38>:    and    $0xf,%eax
   0x00000000004015e2 <+41>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%rsp)
   0x00000000004015e6 <+45>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x00000000004015e9 <+48>:    je     0x40161b <phase_5+98>
   0x00000000004015eb <+50>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x00000000004015f0 <+55>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x00000000004015f5 <+60>:    add    $0x1,%edx
   0x00000000004015f8 <+63>:    cltq   
   0x00000000004015fa <+65>:    mov    0x4022a0(,%rax,4),%eax
   0x0000000000401601 <+72>:    add    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000000000401603 <+74>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x0000000000401606 <+77>:    jne    0x4015f5 <phase_5+60>
   0x0000000000401608 <+79>:    movl   $0xf,0xc(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401610 <+87>:    cmp    $0xb,%edx
   0x0000000000401613 <+90>:    jne    0x40161b <phase_5+98>
   0x0000000000401615 <+92>:    cmp    %ecx,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401619 <+96>:    je     0x401620 <phase_5+103>
   0x000000000040161b <+98>:    call   0x401bed <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401620 <+103>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000401624 <+107>:   ret    
   0x0000000000401625 <+108>:   call   0x401bed <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040162a <+113>:   jmp    0x4015db <phase_5+34>
End of assembler dump.


(gdb) x/s 0x402573
0x402573:   "%d %d"
(gdb) x/16x 0x4022a0
0x4022a0 <array.0>: 0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x4022a8 <array.0+8>:0x0e   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x07    0x00    0x00    0x00


I know that

It reads TWO numbers (the format string "%d %d")
The second number is ANDed with 0xf (keeping last 4 bits) Then it enters a loop where it:
Uses that value to index into array at 0x4022a0
Adds the value to a sum in %ecx
Counts iterations in %edx
Continues until it finds 0xf (15)


Don't delete and repost the same question!!  This is the exact same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79120194/binary-bomb-phase-5-input-two-integers but with part of your reverse-engineering conclusions taken out: "The success conditions are: Must make exactly 11 iterations (%edx must be 0xb) The first input number must match the final sum in %ecx".  Why omit that part?  Did it turn out not to be correct or something?  (It's not, the second input number is the one that's scanned into 8(%rsp).  Look at the registers for scanf's args.)

Note, for your own purposes, deleting negative-scored questions is more of a long term burden to your account than a negative-scored undelted question. For this case it is probably too late to fix the problem, but in your own interest, I recommend to not do that again. Ask me if you want details (I skipped them because they probably would seem only a theoretical problem for future-you).

binary bombs are university homework. There is no point in asking others to solve your homework, you won't learn anything. Start by reversing the code into C or some other high level code you are comfortable with. Then try to fool the algorithm into accepting your input. In this case it's pretty simple. Your description at the end of the question is pretty unless instead, you already know that by reading the code. Instead, factor that information out into code, so you can reason about it.

You printed the array wrong, you used bytes instead of dwords. As such you are only seeing the first 4 items. x/16dw should work better. You have also left out one important fact from your analysis, namely that the values in the array are then used to index the next item, like a linked list. You should find the 0xf in the array then work backwards 11 steps. The starting point and the sum should be your solutions then.
